# Supertabular problem with \input

Tags: input, supertabular

Consider a simple supertabular example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}
a & b \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Suppose I wanted to create a template for dynamically inputting table data using a slightly unusual approach (instead of just inputting table data):

#### `document.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\input{beforetable}
a & b \\
\input{aftertable}
\end{document}
```

With `beforetable.tex` and `aftertable.tex` being `\begin{supertabular}{cc}\endinput` and `\end{supertabular}\endinput`.

That fails with the following error:

> ! Misplaced \noalign.
>   \@tabletail ->\noalign 
>                          {\global \let \@savcr =\ \global \let \=\org@tabula...

The example works if I replace `\input{aftertable}` with its contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\input{beforetable}
a & b \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

What is going on "behind the scenes"?

Comment: The error `Use of \@array doesn't match its definition.` is caused by the missing argument to `\begin{supertabular}`; if you add `{cc}` in the example with `\input{tabledata}` LaTeX doesn't complain.

Comment: You are right. I must have missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens comes from how TeX's `\halign` primitive (used to implement any kind of tabular, array, etc.) works. To draw horizontal lines, or anything else that does not fit in the alignment, one has to use the `\noalign` primitive. This must come first after the `\cr` which closes the previous line. Otherwise, TeX will already have started to typeset the first cell of a new line when meeting `\noalign`. In a typical plain TeX case, we would write

```
\halign{(#)&[#]\cr
  a&b\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
  c&d\cr}
\bye
```

The first line is the "preamble", telling TeX that there will be two columns, and each cell should be typeset with parentheses before and after (round for the first cell of the row, square for the second). There, `#` represents the contents of the cell. Each time `\cr` is met, the closing square bracket from the previous cell will be typeset, and a new line begins. If the next token (after expansion) is `\noalign`, then what follows is set independently of any preamble (here drawing a horizontal line). Otherwise, as in the last row, the preamble is read, and `#` is replaced by the content of the cell. `\bye` is just there to end the file.

In the above, the key is maybe "(after expansion)": after `\cr`, TeX first fully expands what follows to try and see if there might be a `\noalign` hidden in a macro. This is useful for instance in cases such as `\hline` in LaTeX, which expands to `\noalign{...}`.

In your case, `\cr` appears at the end of `\\`. Unfortunately, `\input` is not expandable, and stops TeX from finding a `\noalign` hidden within `\end{supertabular}`, hence the `Misplaced \noalign` error. One solution I found is to put the last `\\` in the ending file. (`filecontents` is a very useful way of creating external files for the sake of examples.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{beforetable}
    \begin{supertabular}{cc}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{aftertable}
    \\
    \end{supertabular}
  \end{filecontents}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\input{beforetable}
a & b 
\input{aftertable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another solution is to replace `\input` by `\@@input` (in a context where `@` is a letter).