# Split table into multiple files with \input

Tags: tables, input

I want to split my table into multiple files:

`\input{table_head.tex}` with following content

```
\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}[r]{ccc}
\addlinespace
\toprule
A & 
B & 
C \\
\midrule
```

`\input{content1.tex}` with following content

```
A1 & B1 & C1 \
```

`\input{content2.tex}` with following content

```
A2 & B2 & C2 \
```

and so on until

`\input{contentX.tex}` with following content

```
AX & BX & CX \
```

and finally the table footer

`\input{table_footer.tex}` with the following content

```
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab_label}
\end{table}
```

Which command should I use? I get errors with `input`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is similar to [Supertabular problem with \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19197/supertabular-problem-with-input): The `\bottomrule` command has to be immediately preceded by a `\\` (or `\tabularnewline`). Even though `\input` works as if you had typed the content directly in most cases, this is one of the occasions where it fails: `\bottomrule` can't find the `\\` from the preceding file. In the answer I linked to, Bruno suggests putting the last `\\` into the footer file, but I assume you want to keep the structure of all the `input` files the same. I would suggest adding `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` at the start of the `table_footer.tex` file, which will act as a newline that doesn't actually change the vertical position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{table_head.tex}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}[r]{ccc}
\addlinespace
\toprule
A & 
B & 
C \\
\midrule
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{input1.tex}
A1 & B1 & C1\\
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{input2.tex}
A2 & B2 & C2\\
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table_foot.tex}
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab_label}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\input{table_head.tex}
\input{input1.tex}
\input{input2.tex}
\input{table_foot.tex}
\end{document}
```